# Calculate AVG in SQL Select statement when some values are NULL

Tags: sql, select, average, coalesce

I have struggled to find a solution to this problem, so any help would be hugely appreciated.

I have two tables, lets call one table_a and one table_b, representing two possible sources of customer orders. They both contain a field called "customer_number" which I am using to outer join table_b to table_a. I am then calculating an average customer order size given the two tables.

Where i struggle is where a customer has an entry in either table, but not in both. Then my average calc returns NULL.

Table_a:

| Customer Number | Total Online Orders |
| --- | --- |
| 123456789 | 1350 |
| 987654321 | 650 |

Table_b:

| Customer Number | Total InStore Orders |
| --- | --- |
| 123456789 | 350 |

So basically the second customer does not have an entry in table_b.

My code as follows:

```
select distinct
a.[customer number],
a.[Total Online Orders],
b.[Total InStore Orders],
coalesce(a.[Total Online Orders] + b.[Total InStore Orders]) / 2 as [Average Order Size]
from table_a a
full outer join table_b b on a.[customer number]=b.[customer number]
```

Results table:

| Customer Number | Total Online Orders | Total InStore Orders | Average Order Size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456789 | 1350 | 350 | 850 |
| 987654321 | 650 | NULL | NULL |

I basically want the results table to show 650 for customer 987654321. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

thanks!

Comment: your code as presented should give an error you are only passing one value to `coalesce`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the brute force method:

```
( coalesce(a.[Total Online Orders], 0) + coalesce(b.[Total InStore Orders], 0)) /
  nullif(case when a.[Total Online Orders] is not null then 1 else 0 end +
         case when b.[Total InStore Orders] is not null then 1 else 0 end, 0)
  )
) as [Average Order Size]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `COALESCE()` for the values of the 2 columns twice:

```
(
  coalesce(a.[Total Online Orders], b.[Total InStore Orders]) + 
  coalesce(b.[Total InStore Orders], a.[Total Online Orders])
) / 2 as [Average Order Size]
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider `UNION` as well, which handles a few other cases too, especially where `customer number` isn't necessarily unique in each table:

```
WITH cte (xtype, [customer number], order_amt) AS (
      select 1 AS xtype, [customer number], [Total Online Orders]  FROM table_a UNION ALL
      select 2 AS xtype, [customer number], [Total InStore Orders] FROM table_b
     )
SELECT [customer number]
     , SUM(CASE WHEN xtype = 1 THEN order_amt ELSE 0 END) AS [Total Online Orders]
     , SUM(CASE WHEN xtype = 2 THEN order_amt ELSE 0 END) AS [Total InStore Orders]
     , AVG(order_amt)                                     AS [Average Order Size]
  FROM cte
 GROUP BY [customer number]
 ORDER BY [customer number]
;
```